# Method return changing on extension

Tags: java, oop

I have a class `ClassA` with some methods returning items:

```
class ClassA {
    ClassA item(...) {...}
    Vector<ClassA> list(...) {...}
}
```

These methods process an input and generate on the fly these kind of items. Now imagine I extend this class:

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {
    ...
}
```

I do not override item() or list() methods in any case, but I'd like them to return a `ClassB` item (or vector of) without casting on the return (which is my current solution now). Is there any way to do so? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your current attempt look like? Can you post your code? It would help to clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: What you could do is override with `ClassB item(...) { return (ClassB) super.item(...); }`. But it will still only be useful when you have a variable that is of the type `ClassB` and not `ClassA`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a third class (ClassC) to hold your ClassA or ClassB items, that is parametrized with a generic type like this:

```
class ClassC<T extends ClassA> {
    T item(...) {...}
    Vector<T> list(...) {...}
}
```

Now you can instantiate ClassC with either a ClassA or ClassB type and never have to worry about class casting.

Comment: This is what I would recommend too, the fact that A returns A, while B extends from A returns B, means there should be a C that manages A and B...

Comment: Ooook it definitely changes my code structure. Luckily I did it generic enough (by my own, too), and I only needed to move some other methods to `ClassC` and change those returned objects from `Vector<ClassA>` to `Vector<ClassB>`. However, I still need to cast the return to `Vector<ClassB>`, as it comes as a `Vector<capture#2-of ? extends ClassA>`. Here comes my Ok.